# Get Queries History from SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, backup, dbatools

I started a new job as DBA, and one of the tasks is to run backups and stuff but since it's my first experience I would like to get a general idea about the databases I'll be managing, for that I want to get a historical tables of executed queries on tables with details such as the date & time of execution, number of queries per each day and so on so that I could define a time window to do some maintenance stuff

Is that possible and if so, how could it be done ?
Thanks

Comment: Download First Reponder kit for checking all stats of database(https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/) and Ola Hallengren script for backup, maintenance job etc(https://ola.hallengren.com/)

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? Do you have any third party monitoring?